# What is the proper way to share the outcome of applying a solution?

Tags: discussion

Related to this question [How can we motivate the asker to provide end results of applying the accepted answer?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4234/3192) but seeing from the other side.

I would like to share with the community the outcome of applying the solutions provided here. Is this acceptable here, and if so, what is the proper way to do this?

I have seen a few askers edit the question to post an "update" section. I guess it doesn't do any harm per se, but I wasn't entirely sure that is the recommended approach. I would like to hear what the community has to say about it.

Comment: dup of https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3255/2322? I think [this answer there](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3256/2322) is the best approach

Comment: Are these questions that you've asked yourself or ones that you've read and applied the answers to your own experiences?

Comment: @enderland Oh, nice, didn't know this was already asked here before.